# How do I (pseudo)randomly generate either number 0 and 1 (Not between)?

Tags: c++, random

How do I (pseudo)randomly generate either 0 or 1?

Note: Not between 0 and 1.

Comment: `r = rand()%2;`. isn't it?

Comment: Rean  `srand` and `rand` see. http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand. Then use integer division

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw Use a salt to avoid repetition

Comment: ah, yes, @EdHeal, `srand(time(0));` then `r = rand()%2;`

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw Thanks, "srand(time(0)); then r = rand()%2;" works for me. Do i delete this question since i got the answer or does anyone wants to answer so i can mark it?

Comment: `int pseudo_randomly() { return 0; }` ;)

Comment: Be careful with `%1`, linear congruential generators can have issues with the low bits. Also, even if you go with the lowest bit, wouldn't bit-masking with `&1` be more efficient than modulo?  I'd be inclined to go with `(rand() >> 16) & 1`.

Comment: @pjs So, "srand(time(0)); then r = (rand() >>16) & 1;" ?

Comment: @LunarBlessings Yup, although the 16 is arbitrary.  A lot of folks would do this by generating a U(0,1) and seeing if it is above or below one half. That's the moral equivalent of checking the highest order magnitude bit in the underlying random integer.

Comment: @pjs Some random number generators only generate numbers up to 32767, so shifting right by 16 will always give you 0. I recommend shifting right by 14 to get the most significant bit.

Comment: @FredOverflow sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11, you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::mt19937_64 generator (seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        std::cout << distribution(generator);
}
```

Or do the C-style suggestion in the comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        std::cout << rand() % 2;
}
```

Comment: +1 Just want to point out that given that the desired result is binary, [`bernoulli_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution) is also suitable.

Comment: With many generators your C-style code will produce output that constantly alternates between 1 and 0, so it's decidedly non-random. With a typical linear congruential generator, you're generally better off keeping more significant bits instead of the least significant bit like this does.

Comment: @Praetorian that was my intention; to produce a random true or false :)